# How to initilize service on module load in new Angular cli format

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am iniliziing service in app.module

```ts
  providers: [
    RoleChildTreeService
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent,RoleChildTreeService]
```

but i got error

> directive_resolver.js:39 Uncaught Error: No Directive annotation found on RoleChildTreeService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just inject the service to the module constructor to get it initialized

```ts
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    RoleChildTreeService
    ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class SomeModule {
  constructor(roleChildService:RoleChildTreeService) {}
}
```

It's a while I saw this but AFAIR it should work.

Comment: but it is not initialising on module load , service construct runs when i open your SomModule

Comment: Here it seems to work https://plnkr.co/edit/ngl6gWdZ6Qyfy0BJ4EM8?p=preview (check the browser console).

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to inject in `bootstrap:[...]`? If you want a **service** which should available to your whole application, then add

```
import { RoleChildTreeService } from './yourPath/roleChildTree.service';
```

in your `app.component.ts` and then

```
providers: [ RoleChildTreeService, ... ]
```

Which you can use anywhere. Please correct me if you want to do something else.

Comment: where should i construct it root component or where i want to use it ?